# Guzzle and Unable to parse response into JSON

Tags: php, xml, json, guzzle

I have a little php api client with this method:

```
private function send($endpoint)
{
    $headers = array();
    $body = $this->xmlSerialiser->convertToXML($this->getQueue());

    try {
        $response = json_decode(
            $this->guzzleClient->post(
                $endpoint,
                $headers, $body
            )
            ->send()
            ->json()
        );

    } catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        $response = array('Error' => $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I'm always receiving

```
Unable to parse response body into JSON: 4 (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I already tried to know an example of server response and seems to be fine:

```
echo (string) $this->guzzleClient->post(
                $endpoint,
                $headers, $body
            )
            ->send()->getBody();
```

and this is the result:

```
<Messages xmlns="http://www.example.com/xxx/3.0">

<GetAccountResponse RequestType="GetAccount">

    <AccountId>xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx</AccountId>

    <Token>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/t3VkEJXC7f6b6G4yPJSZ5QfT2hdSQXUmi0e8cndSYLK4N7mswRHifzwGHLUJYHM17iGL8s=</Token>

</GetAccountResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered myself

the Guzzle documentation says: json method -> Parse the JSON response body and return an array

so in my case I need to switch the json mehod to xml (cos the response is an xml).

Finally this is the result:

```
private function send($endpoint)
{
    $headers = array();
    $body = $this->xmlSerialiser->convertToXML($this->getQueue());

    try {
        $response = (array)(
            $this->guzzleClient->post(
                $endpoint,
                $headers, $body
            )
            ->send()
            ->xml()
        );
    } catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        $response = array('Error' => $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: you can use $response->getBody()->getContents()

Answer (score 1):

Use following code.

```
 $response->getBody()->getContents()
```